# transform time into local time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I have:

`Time.strftime("%I:%M%p")` which gives me the `hr:min AM/PM` format which I need. However it's coming back in UTC and I need it local time zone.

How do I change it to local time zone and keep that same format for time?

Comment: i wish the title of this article would be changed to reflect that the author asked about Time not DateTime. This is leading to misleading search results. I got here from google thinking this was about changing a DateTime object to local time by searching 'local datetime in rails'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also, remember that as of Rails 2.1, Timezones are supported.

in your config/environment.rb file:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

You can find other values by running

```
 rake time:zones:local
```

And Ryan Bates has a great railscast on it:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1

Answer (score 11):

Generally that should work. You may have your time-zone set incorrectly, though:

```
Time.now.strftime("%I:%M%p") # => "12:48PM"
Time.now.utc.strftime("%I:%M%p") # => "04:48PM"
Time.now.utc.getlocal.strftime("%I:%M%p") # => "12:48PM"
Time.now.zone # => "EDT"
```

This can be affected by the TZ environment variable, your OS locale settings, or your Rails configuration in environment.rb.