# Timezone problems in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

In my rails application,After login a user has to create a timesheet entry.The time of creation of the entry is currently my server time.Whereas i want it to be the time of the timezone from where the entry is made i.e if entry is made from any other country.I'm using rails 3 and after searching the web also exact solution cannot be achieved.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't automatically determine the user's timezone, but you can allow them to choose their own timezone. Then you can set `Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone(offset)` before calling update and everything should work correctly. You could also save each user's preference for time zone in your user model.

Comment: options for timezone is a good idea...though req. is abit diff..still i think it should solve the problem..thanx +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this in Rails as the issue is getting the physical location of a user.

It may be worth using JavaScript to populate a (hidden?) field with the current time, which should be taken from user's local machine. You could then explicitly set the created_at field to be this value.

Intrigued to know if Rails can get around this somehow...

Answer (score 0):

If you want, take a look to this question : [transform time into local time in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166475/transform-datetime-into-local-time-in-ruby-on-rails)

And : http://www.wetware.co.nz/blog/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/

Maybe it can helps you.